# Need clarification/input on a curvature dilemma

Tags: optics, curvature, refraction, estimation, distance

Even though I said I'd never waste this much energy arguing with a flat earther, I have a dilemma and need input.

I'm in the Vancouver, Canada area. I've been shown a picture that the person claims is mount Rainier in washington state. Only the top half of the mountain is above the horizon, but all earth curvature calculators I've found say that the curve should hide the whole mountain. I'll admit I haven't quite learnt the curvature calculation, but I can't assume every curvature calculation is wrong. Something here isn't right.

Mount Rainier is roughly 280km or 174 Miles from the camera. The camera is approximately 109m or 357 feet from sea level.

Either every curvature calculator is wrong, that's not mount rainier or I'm losing my mind.

[image: Rainier from US Border]

[image: Original Picture]

[image: Rainier upclose]

Comment: Have you taken into account atmospheric refraction?

Comment: Atmospheric refraction is a strange concept for me because I can't picture anything in the atmosphere causing that much of a distortion. But I'm open to the idea, just seems very strange.

In terms of arguing with a flat earther, believe me, I'm kind of wondering why tf I'm wasting my time on this, but it struck a nerve with me and I'm intent on telling this guy he's full of horse manure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider two effects:

1. the curvature of the earth's surface
2. the [atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction)

---

Let us do the easier part first,
the curvature of the earth's surface (with
$h_1$ the height of the camera,
$h_2$ the height of the hidden bottom-part of the mountain,
$R$ the radius of the earth,
and $d_1+d_2$ the distance between camera and mountain):

[image]

Applying [Pythagoras' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to the green triangle we get:
$$R^2 + d_1^2 = (R + h_1)^2$$
$$R^2 + d_1^2 = R^2 + 2Rh_1 + h_1^2$$
$$d_1^2 = 2Rh_1 + h_1^2$$
Here we can safely neglect the term $h_1^2$ because it is much smaller
than $d_1^2$ and $2Rh_1$.
$$d_1^2 \approx 2Rh_1$$
$$d_1 \approx \sqrt{2Rh_1} \tag{1}$$

Likewise we get for the red triangle:
$$d_2 \approx \sqrt{2Rh_2} \tag{2}$$

The total distance between camera and mountain is $d=d_1+d_2$.
Hence we have:
$$d \approx \sqrt{2Rh_1} + \sqrt{2Rh_2} \tag{3}$$

Resolving for $h_2$ gives
$$h_2 \approx \frac{(d - \sqrt{2Rh_1})^2}{2R} \tag{4}$$
and inserting the numbers we get
$$h_2 \approx \frac{(280\text{ km} - \sqrt{2\cdot 6370\text{ km}\cdot 0.109\text{ km}})^2}{2\cdot 6370\text{ km}} = 4.6\text{ km}$$
which means Mount Rainier (total height $4.4$ km) is completely hidden below the horizon.
So the calculators you mentioned were technically correct.

---

But we didn't account for the [atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction) yet.
Due to the density-gradient of the air (larger density at the ground,
and smaller density at higher altitudes) the light rays will bend downwards.
Because of the large distance this will "lift" the image of the mountain by several degrees.
But I don't know enough to do this calculation.
Hopefully other users can jump in here.

But anyway, this reasoning will probably be too complicated for a
flat-earther's mind. So I would not bother trying to convince him.